# Counterexample for $(p\rightarrow q) \longleftrightarrow (!q \rightarrow\mathord !p) $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Is the statement $$(p\rightarrow q) \longleftrightarrow (!q \rightarrow \mathord!p)  $$ always true? If it is not, provide a counterexample.

Till now I cannot find a counterexample nor prove that the statement is always true.

$!x$ is the negation of $x$.

Comment: Assume $p\implies q$ and $\neg q$. Considering a truth table of $p\implies q$, what truth values are possible for $p$? (This assumes you have available the law of deduction.)

Comment: This is known as the [law of contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: In your question, the ! symbols mean 'NOT' ? or are they operators from some modal logic?

Comment: try to figure it out insiemistically, taking inclusion in place of implication and complementary set in place of negation

Comment: Yes it's a Fallacy.

Comment: of course, $$(p\rightarrow q) \longleftrightarrow (\neg{p} \rightarrow \neg{q})  $$ is not necessarily true

Comment: @mau , Interesting!. Can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: For a triangle $T$, let p be "$T$ is equilateral" and q be "Two base angles of $T$ are the same". This is a counterexample to $(p\implies q)\iff (\neg p\implies\neg q)$. In general, whenever you go from a 'stronger' proposition to a 'weaker' proposition you will get a counterexample.

Comment: Oh sorry , I forgot to note that in the second statement $p$ and $q$ 's order is reversed which mau told.$(p\rightarrow q) \longleftrightarrow \boxed{(\neg{p} \rightarrow \neg{q})}$ . I knew such a statement was wrong, anyway thanks 'mau' and 'user1'

Comment: You actually could find counterexamples in some multi-valued logics.  That said, the question probably assumes classical logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us think about when implication has to be true? Or, equivalently, when it has to be false?

- $p\implies q$ is false if and only if $p$ is true and $q$ is false.
- $\neg q \implies \neg p$ is false if and only if $\neg q$ is true and $\neg p$ is false, i.e. when $q$ is false and  $p$ is true.

We've shown that whenever one of the statements does not hold, then the other also has to be false. It means exactly that these statements are equivalent. We cannot find any counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that I am so late here to try, but, you can use this fact that $$p\longrightarrow q\equiv( \sim p\vee q)$$ Now see that $$p\longrightarrow q\equiv( \sim p\vee \color{blue}q)\equiv(\sim p\vee\color{blue}\sim\color{blue}(\color{blue}\sim\color{blue} q\color{blue}))\equiv(\sim(\sim q)\vee\sim p)\equiv\sim q\longrightarrow\sim p$$

Comment: @SohamChowdhury: Thanks my friend. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice, Babak...hmmm, I wonder where I've seen color used before ? $\;\;$ ;-) $\;\;$

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you're having trouble finding a counterexample *because there is no counterexample!*.

To prove the that the biconditional is true, this is a nice sort of problem where *proof by truth-table* comparison" comes in handy, comparing the evaluation each possible truth value assignment of $p, q$ (i.e., comparing each row), we can determine whether the biconditional is evaluates to true:

See for example, for each row in the following truth table, compare the corresponding truth-value of$\;p\rightarrow q\;$ with $\;\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$.  If the evaluation of each of the connectives *agree* (both true, or both false), for each given row, then the biconditional evaluates true:

[image]

Indeed: We see that for each of the possible $4$ truth-value assignments *for each row of the truth table*, $p \rightarrow q$ and $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p\;$ evaluate to precisely the same truth value. That is precisely what is required for the biconditional to hold. Hence, $$(p\rightarrow q) \longleftrightarrow (\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p)$$

Indeed, by the law of the [**contrapositive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive):

$$(p \rightarrow q) \equiv (\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot q)$$

Comment: boywholived: I hope this helps clarify any lingering questions!

Comment: + Nice Amy. It's not fair you used tables here. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A footnote: The other answers given all assume that the arrow here is the classical material conditional (i.e. has the truth-table given in @amWhy's answer, i.e. makes $p \to q$ equivalent to $\sim p \lor q$ as in @Babak's answer).

It is well worth remarking that the principle that a conditional $p \to q$ is equivalent to $\sim q \to \sim p$  holds in some non-classical logics, including some relevance logics.

If you consider a pair of natural deduction proofs from $p \to q$ to and from  $\sim q \to \sim p$ you'll see you don't need to appeal e.g. to the "irrelevant" classical rule *from a contradiction infer anything* (or to anything which implies it).